# Modify WP-Admin login fields

Tags: wp-admin, login

Hi is it possible to modify the login fields required to login into wp-admin? Say to use the email address instead of the username together with the password to gain access. How would I go about doing that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins which help to do this:

With http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-login/ people can use their email address instead of their username to log into you WordPress install.

Using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/ you can have the WordPress login included in your design, and allow users to modify their account information without logging into the backend.

Comment: Thanks but what about if I want to extend the login further and ask for more fields, apart from the email. Is there maybe a manual may to modify the login system, or more customisable plugins?

Comment: I did a bit of digging. It looks like there are hooks you can override to make this happen, but it really doesn't look straight-forward. You would have to override the form with the login_form hook ( http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/login_form ), then override how logging in is handled using wp_login ( http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_login ). You would have to do your own handling of storing the login information in cookies, and dealing with a failed login. Basically, I think this is something you'd really have to hack WordPress to make happen.